# In Clojure, the program gives an error java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn when I call fact function

Tags: clojure

```
(defn factorial [n fact]
         (if <= n 1) 
          fact
  (factorial (- n 1) (* n fact)))


(defn fact [n]
  (factorial (n 1)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't [n fact] just be [n]. And (factorial (n 1)) just be (factorial 1) (I barely know clojure, but seemed suspicious)

Comment: @Novaterata is correct. Also, your if statement is wrong, it needs to be `(if (<= n 1) then else)`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to write factorial using a parameter to carry the total, but your parentheses aren't quite right.

```
(factorial (n 1))
```

Because n is the first item in a list, it gets called as a function. But being a number, it can't be used that way.

To call the factorial function (with n as input and 1 as the initial total), you probably mean

```
(defn fact [n]
  (factorial n 1))
```

There are additional problems in your factorial function.

```
(if <= n 1)
```

`<=` is a function, so it needs to be called when used as an argument to if

```
(if (<= n 1)
  ...
```

The recursive call to factorial is pretty much what you want for your solution, but there're some mismatched parentheses, here's what you probably meant

```
(defn factorial [n fact]
   (if (<= n 1)
      fact
      (factorial (- n 1) (* n fact))))
```

However, there's a bit of correctness/idiomatic clojure slang that can be used, here's a slightly better way to do your full solution

```
(defn factorial [n total]
  (if (<= n 1)
     total
     (recur (dec n) (* n total))))

(defn fact [n]
   (factorial n 1))
```

Although, if you use the call stack to carry the total, you can do slightly better

```
(defn factorial [n]
   (if (<= n 1)
      1
      (* n (factorial (dec n)))))
```

You could restructure this slightly to use `recur`, which would give you some slightly better performance, but I assume this is an academic exercise and you can look at other answers (such as [Alan Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402784/2039914) for that).

Answer (score 0):

You can see 2 examples showing of solving the factorial problem the using recursion compared to loop/recur in this question:

[How to use tail recursion correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379741/how-to-use-tail-recursion-correctly/42380515#42380515)